# Presence Insights SDK not working correctly

Tags: analytics, ibm-cloud, presenceinsights

I am working on the Presence Insights SDK and I have a issue with analytics. I take the phone and go to the zone that I have configured already in the Presence Insights website. The zone says that there is 1 visitor. After that, I go outside a little bit and I return to the previous zone. The zone says that there is 1 visitor. It doesn't increase.

But when I go to the other zone and return to the previous zone, the previous zone says that there are 2 visitors. I don't know if the SDK is still beta version. It doesn't seem to work correctly. When does the zone increase the visitor if a phone enters the zone?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the exit condition was not met.  Exit events are triggered when:

1. The device is detected by another beacon or sensor, at a different zone.
2. The device is not detected for a period greater than **Device Timeout**.

For the case where the device travels from zone to zone, the exit event is fired immediately after detecting the device in the new zone.

For the case where the device moves outside, the exit event will be fired after the device is not detected by any beacon/sensor for a time period greater than  **Device Timeout**.

**Device Timeout** can be configured at **Settings -> General -> Application Settings**. The default value is 900000 ms (15 mins).

It looks like during this test the device didn't stay outside of beacon or sensor range long enough, so an exit event was never triggered. When it returned to the beacon or sensor range, PI interpreted it as the same visit.